# decimal to binary in assembly mips

Tags: arrays, binary, decimal, mips, qtspim

I am trying to convert a decimal number to a binary number. I want to store the modulus in an array and then print the result. The result must be printed backwards. This is my code so far. When it runs, a message appears saying `unaligned address,exception 5`. Here is my code so far

```
.data

prompt1: .asciiz "\n\n Please give the decimal number:"

prompt2: .asciiz "The binary number is:"

array: .space 32

linefeed: .asciiz "\n"

enterkey: .asciiz "Press any key to end program."




.text

main:

li $t0,0

li $t3,2

  li $s0, 0

  li $a0, 0

#t1-to hold number




li $v0, 4 #syscall to print string

la $a0, prompt1  #address of string to print

syscall

li $v0, 5 #syscall to read an integer

syscall

move $t1, $v0  #move the number to read into $t1


for: 

bge $s0, 8, end_for

  div $t1,$t3

  mflo $t1 #diversion

  mfhi $t1 #modulus

  sw $t1,array($t0) #save the number to read into array

  addi $t0,$t0,4

  addi $s0,$s0,1


  j for

end_for:



# print out a line feed

li $v0,4 # code for print_string

la $a0,linefeed # point $a0 to linefeed string

syscall # print linefeed



li $v0,1

move $a0,$t0

syscall 


# print out a line feed

li $v0,4 # code for print_string

la $a0,linefeed # point $a0 to linefeed string

syscall # print linefeed

# wait for the enter key to be pressed to end program

li $v0,4 # code for print_string

la $a0,enterkey # point $a0 to enterkey string

syscall # print enterkey

# wait for input by getting an integer from the user (integer is ignored)

li $v0,5 # code for read_int

syscall #get int from user --> returned in $v0

# All done, thank you!

li $v0,10 # code for exit

syscall # exit program
```

Comment: run the code in the qtspim debugger and find out where in your program the exception happens.

Answer (score 0):

i made some improvements but still nothing.This time i think
that it doesn't store the values in the array

.data

prompt1: .asciiz "\n\n Please give the decimal number:"

prompt2: .asciiz "The binary number is:"

array:.align 2

```
  .space 32
```

linefeed: .asciiz "\n"

enterkey: .asciiz "Press any key to end program."

.text

main:

li $t0,0

li $t3,2

li $s0, 0

li $a0, 0

## t1-to hold number

li $v0, 4 #syscall to print string

la $a0, prompt1  #address of string to print

syscall

li $v0, 5 #syscall to read an integer

syscall

move $t1, $v0  #move the number to read into $t1

for:

bge $s0, 8, end_for

div $t1,$t3

mflo $t2 #div

mfhi $t4 #mod

move $t1,$t2

li $v0,1 # code for print_int

move $a0,$t4 # put result in $a0

syscall # print out the result

sw $t4,array($t0) #save the number to read into array

addi $t0,$t0,4

addi $s0,$s0,1

j for

end_for:

forprint:

bge $s0, 8, end_forprint

lw $t4,array($t0) #save the number to read into array

li $v0,1 # code for print_int

move $a0,$t4 # put result in $a0

syscall # print out the result

addi $t0,$t0,4

addi $s0,$s0,1

j forprint

end_forprint:

## print out a line feed

li $v0,4 # code for print_string

la $a0,linefeed # point $a0 to linefeed string

syscall # print linefeed

## wait for the enter key to be pressed to end program

li $v0,4 # code for print_string

la $a0,enterkey # point $a0 to enterkey string

syscall # print enterkey

## wait for input by getting an integer from the user (integer is ignored)

li $v0,5 # code for read_int

syscall #get int from user --> returned in $v0

## All done, thank you!

li $v0,10 # code for exit

syscall # exit program